# parse WAV and MIDI files for machine learning

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, wav, midi, one-hot-encoding

Is there any algorithm or library out there that parses WAV file data and MIDI file data into something more manipulable (such as one-hot vectors) so they can be used in a machine learning project? I understand that these are two very different types of files so they must be processed differently.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "discretize"? The data in WAV and MIDI files already is discrete.

Comment: @CL. I mean to convert the data into something more manipulable (such as one-hot vectors) so they can be used in a machine learning project